# SQL Server full-text search using thesaurus and prefix form together

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, thesaurus, formsof

Here is a sample table with full-text search on `FTSdata` field:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tTest (Id INT, FTSdata VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.tTest (Id, FTSdata) VALUES
(1, 'foo WordA'),
(2, 'foo WordAaabbb'),
(3, 'WordB bar'),
(4, 'WordBbbaaa bar');
```

I would like to find all these records no matter whether users typed "WordA" or "WordB".

My thesaurus looks like this:

```
<expansion>
    <sub>WordA</sub>
    <sub>WordB</sub>
</expansion>
```

I need something like

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.tTest
WHERE CONTAINS(FTSdata, 'FORMSOF (THESAURUS, "WordA*")');
```

But unfortunately asterisk is not supported in FORMSOF predicate.

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm having similar problems.

Answer (score 4):

Its true you cannot use `*` with THESAURUS but you can do something like this.
 
**Query**

```
    SELECT FTSdata
    FROM dbo.tTest2
    WHERE CONTAINS(FTSdata, 'FORMSOF (THESAURUS, Word) OR "Word*"')
```

This will return any thesaurus defined by you for the word "Word" and also any words starting with "Word"

The reuslt set I get back using this query is as follows:
 
**Result Set**

```
FTSdata
foo WordA
foo WordAaabbb
WordB bar
WordBbbaaa bar
```

**FTS XML FILE**

```
<expansion>
    <sub>Word</sub>
    <sub>WordA</sub>
    <sub>WordB</sub>
</expansion>
```

Comment: I want to get `WordBbbaaa bar` when I'm looking for `WordA` (not `Word`). This phrase is typed by user and I cannot crop received words.